# set Value in text box depends to another text box using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

Suppose I have label which text show total amount and two extra text box first one for discount in percentage and and second one for discount after percentage calculation.

User free to enter both if user enter in second text box total discount then first text box show percentage of that entered amount again if user enter in first text box discount percentage then second text box will show calculated discount. Remember Total amount in label text.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this concept:

```
    $scope.itemNames = [
    {item: 'Shirt', qty: 2, price: 600},
    {item: 'Caps', qty: 3, price: 100},
    {item: 'Sunglass', qty: 2, price: 300}
  ];

  $scope.total = function () {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.itemNames, function (value) {
      total += value.qty * value.price;
    });
    return total;
  };
  var totalAmt = $scope.total();
  $scope.discountPer = function () {
    if ($scope.totalDisc) {
      $scope.discount = ($scope.totalDisc *100)/totalAmt;
    }
  };
  $scope.totalDiscount = function () {
    if ($scope.discount) {
      $scope.totalDisc = (totalAmt*$scope.discount)/100;
    }
  };
```

In your html:

```
<div class="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Unit Price in Rs</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in itemNames">
        <td>{{item.item}}</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="item.qty"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="item.price"></td>
        <td>{{item.qty * item.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <label>Discount</label>  
    <input type="number" name="discount" ng-change="totalDiscount()" ng-model="discount">% <br/>
    <label>Total Discount</label>  
    <input type="number" name="totalDiscount" ng-change="discountPer()" ng-model="totalDisc"/><br/>

    <span class="col-md-offset-5 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-offset-5">Total : {{total() - totalDisc}} </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply but i dont want like this

Comment: what type of result you are expecting?

Comment: I my case total label amount will fix

Comment: text box value will change accordinglly

Comment: Thanks Jagadeesh Thank you very much you resolved my issue

Comment: Once again Thanks Jagdeesh

Comment: @user2034775 Please accept this answer, so that it will helps me to get more bounty...